# loop with if statement in vuejs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to make a loop to show button with if statement and another button when else but the main loop keeps giving 3 buttons instead of one but when I remove else statement the code works fine, so where is the miss

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"
      v-for="orderedLesson in orderedLessonsInSeries"
      :class=" orderedLesson.id == lesson.id ? 'active' : '' ">
    <span class="col-11 text-left">
      <button v-for="userCompletedLesson in userCompletedLessons"
        v-if="userCompletedLesson.id == orderedLesson.id"
        style="text-decoration: none; border: none; background-color: transparent;">
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i>
      </button>
      <button v-else style="text-decoration: none; border: none; background-color: transparent;">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-lg"></i>
      </button>
      <strong>{{ orderedLesson.title }}</strong>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the v-else is in another scope from the v-if. 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if

Try to do the v-for in an outher <template>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mixing between v-if and v-for. If you want to check if the lesson is completed or not, you can create a separate method:

```
<span class="col-11 text-left">
  <button
    v-if="isCompleted(orderedLesson)"
    style="text-decoration: none; border: none; background-color: transparent;">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i>
  </button>
  <button v-else style="text-decoration: none; border: none; background-color: transparent;">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-lg"></i>
  </button>
  <strong>{{ orderedLesson.title }}</strong>
</span>
```

`isCompleted` method

```
methods: {
  isCompleted (lesson) {
    let completedLessonIds = []
    if (this.userCompletedLessons) {
      completedLessonIds = this.userCompletedLessons.map(l => l.id) // you can move it to computed properties
    }
    return completedLessonIds.includes(lesson.id)
  }
}
```